# How to make other threads wait while executing a function

Tags: c, multithreading, scheduling

So, I am having a semaphore of value 2 and inside it another semaphore where only one of the threads that entered semaphore 1 can go at a time. Inside the binary semaphore the thread that entered should print a line that it is in, then another thread should say "Hello" and then the thread should exit the semaphore CR and say "Bye". My question is, can the thread that goes in the semaphore signal another thread that it is in? And also, while this

```
1: "Im in",
2: "Hello thread no 1"
1: "Bye"
```

can I make other threads wait for the conversation to happen/end ?

You don't need to bother to write code, I just need an explanation of how to send the 'id' to the thread and make other threads wait while conversation is on.

Comment: it is just a void that has a printf("Hello, this is thread no #");. Lets call it a function.

Comment: Are you using POSIX threads? If so maybe [this will help](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_key_create.html), if it's a simple situation where a mutex and passing the data as the third parameter to `pthread_create()` would work then you should try that too.

Comment: are you creating windows thread or posix thread?

Comment: @Sudipta Kumar Sahoo Im using posix threads. I have the code, and the threads get created, but now i want to pass an id to a thread , which would invoke the function that prints the "Hello thread number #".

Comment: @iharob You suggest that I have the suggested key as in the link, but can I make other processes wait while the conversation is on (while Key == 0 for example)

Comment: @JovanIvanoski Yes "*for example*" the details would be decided by you, but you can do that or pass a common `void *` pointer to all the threads through the last parameter to `pthread_create()`.

Comment: you can use waitpid() to wait for the other thread to complete its execution.

Comment: Condition variables are used to make threads wait on a specific condition.